# StreamWriter is overwriting each line, I need them Listed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following which searches the domain and lists out each user. I am writing them to a text file. The problem is each user name as it is found overwrites the other one.

I need them listed one under the other. Have I misplaced the Using statement?

Thanks again guys.

```
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
    'Name place to write file to
    Dim strFile As String = "C:\MyFile.txt"
    Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
     'get list of all users on domain and write to file
    de.Path = "WinNT://domain.blah.com"
    For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            sw.WriteLine(d.Name)
        End Using
    Next
```

Comment: Yes, you misplaced the Using statement, as the file should be opened once for all de.Children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're opening a new `StreamWriter` for each line in your list. Try swapping the creation of the stream writer and the loop:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
        sw.WriteLine(d.Name)
    Next
End Using
```